# Inline event handler in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS, and I have almost read all the documents from the official site.

It is a wonderful framework to  build self-contained and reusable view components, however I have some confusion at the moment:

**1 MVC vs Self-contained**

As said, reactjs is thought of as the `V` in the MVC, while business logic should not be put inside as downloading data from the server and save data to server.

However it seems that a self-contained component control the model,controller and view could make sense sometime .

Take the `CommentBox` from the tutorial(http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) as an example:

The `CommentBox` itself take the handler of loading/representing/updating comments, there is no problem in the example, since this component have no interactive with others.

How about if we want to use a `CommentBox` with a different source which may have different loading/updating manner. In this case, use ReactJS just for representing seems make more sense.

So I wonder which is the reactjs way?

**2 In-line events registering**

Code:

```
  render: function() {
    var value = this.state.value;
    return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
```

As shown we have to register `onChange` event in the markup(jsx), is this what we tried our best to avoid ? How about if we want to bind the same events to a list of elements, generally we use :

```
 $(".selector").click("...");
```

Now we have to add the events to every node.

Is it possible to split events from the markup?

Answer (score 2):

### MVC vs Self-contained

I would say that in the `CommentBox` example, they did not want to introduce Flux or any other architecture, just for the sake of simplicity. Always decouple as much as you can the logic from your components. API calls do not belong to components. [This is an interesting reading](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) by Dan Abramov that explains how to build a good components hierarchy.

### In-line events registering

This is actually a React pro. It is declarative and prevents you from the jQuerish shortcuts of DOM selectors, which is the old imperative approach. The jQuery mindset is not easy to dump. If you haven't yet, I suggest you to read [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html).